# idVendor and idProduct for USB

Tags: usb, drivers, usb-storage, vendor-id, product-id

I am very new to USB interfacing and I am trying to build an application for WINCE 2013 device. In my device, one vendor's (let suppose 'X') VID and PID are using for USB mass storage device class.

Now, I have specific use case where communication should be built on USB rndis class. For this communication purpose we are using Microsoft generic rndis driver as is (not a custom one). So, can I use the X's VID and PID(which I am using for MASS STORAGE class now) for the Rndis class too or need to purchase a new one again. I know that I can use any VID and PID during development stage but I need VID and PID's for production devices.

Or can I go with Microsoft VID, PID and compatible id's compatible for Microsoft generic rndis driver by changing only the Serial Number for devices?

Please suggest and thanks in advance! :-)

(Do let me know if the query is too vague to understand.)

Answer (score 1):

First, "VID" stands for "Vendor ID". It is formally illegal to use someone else vendor ID for your product, unless you have some permission to do so. If your are designing a USB product, your company should apply for unique VID at USB-IF.ORG

Second, the host choice of driver software is defined by the class of device, not by VID or PID. The "PID" stands for "Product ID". It is built-in by device maker to differentiate between different USB products. Therefore it would be extremely unwise for a manufacturer to use the same PID for different devices with different functional classes.

Comment: Hi chen,
I'm working on a hardware for which BSP is already configured and it uses VID and PID obtained legally from a Vendor and are only configured for MASS STORAGE DEVICE class in registry.
Windows loads the correct driver if it matches with VID and PID, if i'm not wrong. Windows Generic Rndis driver suffice our requirement and what legalities are imbibed for one who uses Microsoft VID and PID for production devices.
These Production devices are used only by service based people from my company and not everyone. Can you please share any relevant suggestions or documentation or links.

Comment: @praveen, ok then, if you are making a backdoor, then you can use whatever you want as long as a user isn't suppose to use that port. VID and PID are used for proprietary drivers, and if there is none, the system picks a generic driver based on device class. However, the RNDIS is Microsoft proprietary protocol, so it might be necessary to use MSFT VID, PID, and RNDIS class all together to get the desired functionality, that I don't know. So your question should read: "Can I use non-microsoft VID and PID for my RNDIS device to work with MSFT stack by default?"

Comment: @chen, Thanks for the reply and how to use VID and PID of Microsoft legally. can there be any way of it or it is only for device development use?

Comment: @praveen, did you ask Microsoft?